# Some colors don't display, neither do some icons in Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I use Vuetify and the "secondary" color doesn't show, as the "github" icon.
Here is my code:

```
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-bottom-sheet v-model="aPropos" inset>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on: sheet }">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
            <v-btn
              class="mx-2"
              fab
              dark
              small
              v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...sheet }"
              color="secondary">
              <v-icon dark>mdi-help-circle-outline</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <span>À propos</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
      <v-sheet class="text-center">
        <div class="my-3">
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="mx-2" color="primary" fab x-small dark v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-facebook</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Facebook</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn href="https://twitter.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="mx-2" color="primary" fab x-small dark v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-twitter</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Twitter</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx" target="_blank" class="mx-2" color="primary" fab x-small dark v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-linkedin</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>LinkedIn</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn href="mailto:xxx" class="mx-2" color="secondary" fab x-small dark v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-email</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Courriel</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn href="http://xxx" target="_blank" class="mx-2" color="orange" fab x-small dark v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-firefox</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Site internet</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </div>
        <div class="my-3">Licence</div>
        <div class="my-3">
          <v-btn href="https://github.com/xxx" target="_blank" class="ma-2" tile outlined color="primary">
            <v-icon left>mdi-github</v-icon> Page GitHub du projet
          </v-btn>
        </div>
        <v-btn
          class="mt-6"
          text
          color="error"
          @click="aPropos = !aPropos"
        >Fermer</v-btn>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
  </div>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

The "email" button should be light blue and the logo next to "Page GitHub" should be the GitHub logo, not a striked telephone.

I precise, because I already searched for similar questions, that I use "v-app" at the top of my app, to wrap it all (all the other features display correctly).
I use the last version of VueJS and Vuetify (everytime I build I fetch the last version).

If anybody has a clue why I have this result, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually running `npm install @mdi/font --save-dev` solves the "GitHub" icon problem.
The color problem wasn't a problem, surprisingly it's the color they've chosen to be secondary.